# Generate password hash in java like openssl passwd -1

Tags: java, passwords, openssl

Is there an easy way in Java to generate password hashes in same form as generated by "openssl passwd -1".

Example:

```
# openssl passwd -1 test
$1$Gt24/BL6$E4ZsrluohHFxtcdqCH7jo.
```

I'm looking for a pure java solution that does not call openssl or any other external program.

Thanks
Raffael

Answer (score 3):

[The openssl docs](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/passwd.html) describe the `-1` option as: "Use the MD5 based BSD password algorithm 1."

[Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) is a java cryptogrqphy library, as is [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). Jasypt is slightly more complicated, but more configurable.

I don't know that much about crypto, but my guess is that the password generated by openssl breaks down as:
`$1$` - specifies that this was generated using the MD5 scheme
`Gt24/BL6` - 8 byte salt
`$` - delimiter
`E4ZsrluohHFxtcdqCH7jo.` - hash

so it looks like Jasypt's [BasicPasswordEncryptor](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/apidocs/org/jasypt/util/password/BasicPasswordEncryptor.html) might be what you want-

Comment: I doubt it, unless BasicPasswordEncryptor is intentionally designed to be compatible with the flaky FreeBSD MD5Crypt.

Comment: well it uses MD5, an 8 byte salt, and 1000 iterations (which appears to be what the crypt algorithm uses - http://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-hackers@freebsd.org/msg23405.html), which leaves the implementation itself I guess . . .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
MessageDigest md = null;
md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
md.update(pPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte raw[] = md.digest();
String hash = BASE64Encoder.encodeBuffer(raw);
```

The Java BASE64Encoder source can be found on the net.

Comment: Or you can use the base64encoder from Commons Coded : http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: `$` is not a valid Base64 code. I think there is more going on than just Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can find source code for the C language version [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/lib/libcrypt/crypt.c?rev=1.2). It should be straightforward to convert it to pure Java.